# Create javascript input

Tags: javascript

I have a function to delete table rows like this:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
    var id = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id");
    var idutente = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id_utente");
    var nomeutente = $(this).parents("tr").attr("nomeutente");

    if(confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja excluir a requisição?'))
    {
        $.ajax({
           url: './deleteutente1',
           type: 'GET',
           data: {id: id, idutente: idutente, nomeutente: nomeutente},
           error: function() {
              alert('Algo está errado!');
           },
           success: function(data) {
                $("#"+id).remove();
                alert("Requisição removida com sucesso");  
           }
        });
    }
});
```

When the alert was displayed, I want a textarea to be displayed to the user to put the reason for removal and insert it into a database table, but I don't understand how to do that.

Comment: Avoid `confirmation window` , try to use modal, like bootstrap modal, you will have a full control to do whatever you want to do.

Comment: afasik there is no attribute by name `id_utente` & `nomeutente`. Use `data` attribute for custom properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple solution, use `prompt()`:

```js
const reason = prompt('Why did you remove [whatever]?');
console.log(reason);
```

I would advise replacing your alert with this:

```js
const reason = prompt('Requisição removida com sucesso.\n\nWhy did you remove [whatever]?');
console.log(reason);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prompt('message') : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Answer (score 0):

```
const userAnswer = prompt('Why?');
```

`console.log(userAnswer);` -> This will give you the the output to the console, however it'll be much more user friendly to create a modal instead. Take a look at the below link with the modal examples I found: https://codepen.io/timjackleus/pen/yOWpGQ , https://codepen.io/Ashbo/pen/bdvadR

Hope it helps :)